# How to change values all other rows in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-7

I have a DB table like following

```
-----------------------------
id    name        featured  |
1     jhon           1      |
2     Doe            0      |
3     Mark           1      |
4     Hyk            0      |
-----------------------------
```

When I will change any of the `featured` column value 0 to 1, all other `featured` value will be set to 0. For instance if change the `featured` value where `id=2`, the updated table should look like

```
-----------------------------
id    name        featured  |
1     jhon           0      |
2     Doe            1      |
3     Mark           0      |
4     Hyk            0      |
-----------------------------
```

What will be the appropriate eloquent query ? Assuming the Model is `Player` and DB table name is `players`.

*Laravel version: 7.30.4*

Comment: What you have tried yet

Answer (score 3):

You maybe call update on all players:

```
Player::update(['featured' => 0]);
```

To update a specific Player, use a unique column like `id` to affect only that player,

```
$playerId = 2;        
Player::whereId($playerId)->update(['featured' => 1]);
```

Comment: I would prefer something like `Player::where('featured', '=', '1')->where('id', '!=', $id)->update(['featured' => 0]);` instead of updating all records.

Comment: Your solution will not update $id feature value 1.

Comment: It defines "value where id=2"

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
$player = Player::where('id', $id)
            ->update(['featured' => 1]);

// Make sure that you have featured column datatype is tinyint or int
// if you have datatype varchar or text type you have to 
   ->update(['featured' => '1']) like this
```